# Simulate Keyboard key with keybd_event to UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to simulate keyboard pressure and release on an Univesal Windows App. 
I tried this code on a wpf and it works, but using the same code on a UWP does not work.
Is it a limit for windows app or is there any other problem?

Thanks.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]    
static extern void keybd_event(byte key, byte scan, int flags, int extraInfo);

const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
const byte KEY_A = 0x41 //A character

public static void simulateKeyDown(KEY_A)
{
   keybd_event(KEY_A, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void simulateKeyUp(KEY_A)
{
 keybd_event(KEY_A, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a UWP app you have to use the Input Injection APIs and capability for simulating keyboard (and mouse, touch, etc.).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection